# ORA-02086: database (link) name is too long

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Can somebody throw a light on how to negotiate this error. What probably is obvious is that a string is very long to be inserted in the DB. Other than the fact that we need to cut down on length, is there some way of negotiating this problem?

Comment: A database link name can be up to 128 characters. Why are you hitting this limit? Why can you not use a shorter name?

Comment: well...its not exactly a name. we are inserting another "Insert statement" in a particular column which is certainly pretty long. I did read that only 128 characters can be inserted.  I have reduced all spaces and removed unnecessary values, but still I can manage only 204 characters. Is there any way we could come around this issue?

Comment: well, I cant paste the code here from my work, but what i did was, removed two nullable fields which, if not null, had pretty lengthy strings. However it would have been good to have had that info too.

Comment: Oracle VARCHAR2 columns are limited to 4000 characters max, I believe.  How is the column into which you're trying to put your string declared?

Comment: It's important to see your code, because it sounds like you're doing something very strange or wrong. The only way I know to get this error is when I attempt to CREATE a database link, where the link is only a name (identifier) to another database. The DML you perform should NOT be a factor in hitting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create the database link using

```
create public database link 
mylink
connect to 
remote_username
identified by 
mypassword 
using 'tns_service_name';
```

in this mylink you are using should be less than 128 characters

After creating the database link use for example

```
insert into remote_username.remote_table@mylink values ('a','b','c');
```